# Typescript: how to get access to the navigator.connection property

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to get access to the [NetworkInformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation) interface using a simple TypeScript function like the following one:

```
private checkNetworkConnection(): void {
const connection = Navigator.connection
  || navigator.mozConnection 
  || navigator.webkitConnection;
 const type = connection.type;
 console.log('CONNECTION TYPE: %o', type);
 console.log('DOWNLINK: %o', connection.downlink);
}
```

The fact is that I keep getting back the `connection is undefined` error. Looking around on SO I found that the people that use Cordova extend the type definitions of Typescript importing `@types/cordova-plugin-network-information` but that doesn't solve my issue.

A working StackBlitz example can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ieaiw4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

1. https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#-dfn-connection-dfn-attribute
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API

Comment: Only Chrome support this and the 'type' property is not available. This feature is not complete and not production ready.

Comment: It's not true that only Chrome supports this feature. You can see it working on Firefox 61 as well and the documentation I reported above is taken from MDN. My question is how to access `navigator.connection` in typescript, whenever it's available, obviously.

Comment: In order to access property which are unknown for Typescript, you can do this `Navigator['connection']`

Answer (score 0):

This NPM package brings that type into Angular:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/network-information-types

**Add the package to your project:**

```
npm install network-information-types
```

**Then update your typescript.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [
        "./node_modules/network-information-types"
    ]
  },
}
```

Obligatory note: At this stage only Chromium really supports this type.

Comment: I do hope that at least Firefox brings it in via a permission request since it is useful in PWA's (that's why I'm looking into it).